# MVC project, Error because model not passed to view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

**The Scenario is this**...I goto the login screen on my web app.  I login with wrong username/password.  I get an error on the line in my HTML for tab-6 @HTML.Partial("../../Account/Register") because the RegisterModel is not passed in(Exact error below).  Well I'm not doing anything with the Register screen, just logging in.

However, I think the problem is because the Register section is always loaded.  So I'm thinking, I don't need to pass in both LogOnModel and RegisterModel, to fix the problem, but maybe should not load the Register page until it is specifically called, I think?  Is that the correct thing to do and how would I load the Register page only when it is called/clicked. I'm using JQuery UI tabs and asp.net mvc.

**ERROR:**
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Portal.Web.Models.LogOnModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Portal.Web.Models.RegisterModel'.

Thanks a lot!

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style=" position:relative; border:0px;"   >
                <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">                        
                    <li><a href="#tabs-1" >Home</a></li>                        
                    <li><a href="#tabs-2" >Statistics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-3" >Topo Maps</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-4" >FAQs</a></li>
                    <li style="display:none;"><a href="#tabs-5">Login</a></li>
                    <li style="display:none;"><a href="#tabs-6">SignUp</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-hide ui-tabs-panel">@Html.Partial("../Home/Home") </div>
                <div id="tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-hide ui-tabs-panel">@Html.Partial("../Statistics/Statistics")</div>
                <div id="tabs-3" class="ui-tabs-hide ui-tabs-panel">@Html.Partial("../Maps/Maps")</div>
                <div id="tabs-4" class="ui-tabs-hide ui-tabs-panel">@Html.Partial("../Home/FAQs")</div>                                     
               <div id="tabs-5" class="ui-tabs-hide ui-tabs-panel">@Html.Partial("../Account/LogOn")</div>                  
               <div id="tabs-6" class="ui-tabs-hide ui-tabs-panel">@Html.Partial("../Account/Register")</div>  

            </div>
```

Here is my AccountController with action method

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

As Requested Here is the additional code:

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Show the code from the logon GET action, something is happening there when loading the view that isn't happening when you return the view in the post action

Comment: I added the GET action at the bottom. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that you've set your partial view to inherit from the appropriate model. At the top of your partial view code, you should have a line like this.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Portal.Web.Models.LogOnModel>" %>
```

Comment: Yes, in my LogOn view I have LogOnModel and in my Register view I have RegisterModel. So all is ok there.